# По проекту или на проект?

Tags: стилистика, предлоги

принял участие в подготовке заключения по проекту закона «Об...»/ на проект закона «Об...» - как предлог нужно употребить?

Answer (score 1):

Все плохо. Норамативно: "заключение о". Но, увы, норме следуют единичные источники. Что Вам посоветовать, даже не знаю. Вряд ли Вас поймут правильно, напши Вы нормативную конструкцию. 
Думаю, что "заключение на" менее неправильно. Но - субъективно, доказать не могу.

Answer (score 1):

Если взять нормативное "заключение о", то можно продолжить так: "заключение о работе проекта". А слово "заключение" здесь обязательно? Может быть, другую конструкцию использовать?

Comment: Это, конечно, не мне рещать, то вообще-то "заключение" - это название документа. "Прошу Вас дать своё заключение..."